# Why Swift compiler cannot infer a type?

Tags: swift

I've developed this generic method to execute requests:

```
func executeRequest<T, S, E>(_ request : RequestBuilder<T>,
                             map: (@escaping (T) -> S)) -> RepositoryResult<S, E> {
    return RepositoryResult().doTask { result in
        request.execute{ (response, error) in
            // do some stuff
            result.notifySuccess(value: map(body))
        }
}
```

My map function is defined in a subclass with generic types:

```
class BaseMapper<R, U> {
    class func transform(_ dataModel:R) -> U {
        fatalError("Override this method")
    }
    // other generic methods
}

class HomeMapper:BaseMapper<HomeDTO, Home> {
    override class func transform(_ dataModel: HomeDTO) -> Home {
        return Home(customerFirstName: dataModel.customerFirstName,
                balance: MoneyMapper.transform(dataModel.balance),
                accounts: AccountSummaryMapper.listTransform(dataModel.summaries))
    }
}
```

If I call the request executor method passing directly the map function like that:

```
 func getHomeInfo() -> RepositoryResult<Home, HomeError> {
    return executeRequest(HomeAPI.getMyHomeWithRequestBuilder(), map: HomeMapper.transform)
 }
```

I believe Swift compiler is crashing because it returns several random errors: "Segmentation fault: 11". Otherwise, if I call the method specifying the "S" return type, it works:

```
func getHomeInfo() -> RepositoryResult<Home, HomeError>{
    return executeRequest(HomeAPI.getMyHomeWithRequestBuilder(), map: { (homeDTO) -> Home in
        HomeMapper.transform(homeDTO)
    })
}
```

Furthermore, using a Mapper that doesn't inherit from BaseMapper and passing the function directly, it also works. Another thing that I don't understand is that RxSwift has a map function that works calling it with my first option...

**Why swift compiler cannot infer "S" type? Why swift compiler is crashing and can't tell which line is crashing and why?**

Comment: Compiler crashing means there is a bug in the compiler. To be honest, your object model seems a bit too complicated.

Comment: Be sure to file a [bugreport](https://bugreport.apple.com) with that crash.

Comment: I've just reported the crash

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: associatedtypes

```
protocol Mappable {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype S

    static func transform(_ dataModel:T) -> S
}

class MapperHome : Mappable {
    static func transform(_ dataModel: HomeDTO) -> Home {
        return Home(customerFirstName: dataModel.customerFirstName,
                balance: MoneyMapper.transform(dataModel.balance),
                accounts: AccountSummaryMapper.listTransform(dataModel.summaries))
    }
}

func getHomeInfo() -> RepositoryResult<Home, HomeError>{
    return executeRequest(HomeAPI.getMyHomeWithRequestBuilder(), map: MapperHome.transform)
}
```

I don't understand why this code compiles and using inheritance instance of implementation of a protocol it doesn't... I don't know if it's a compiler bug or my fault.

Comment: A compiler crashing is always the fault of the compiler. It is a major part of its job to not crash even on most convoluted code.